# concise and fast zip operation on lists of lists in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, list-manipulation

Is there a more concise and time efficient way to achieve the following `zip` operation in Python? I am pairing lists of lists together to make new lists, as follows:

```
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
>>> for x, y in zip(a, b):
...   print zip(*[x, y])
... 
[(1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 12)]
[(4, 13), (5, 14), (6, 15)]
```

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't really see a better way other than replacing:

```
print zip(*[x, y])
```

with:

```
print zip(x,y)
```

---

If you're really working with 2 element lists, you could probably just do:

```
print zip( a[0], b[0] )
print zip( a[1], b[1] )
```

(It'll be slightly more efficient as you leave off 1 zip, but I'm not convinced that it is more *clear*, which is what you should really be worried about).

---

If you're really into compact code, you can use `map`:

```
map(zip,a,b) #[[(1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 12)], [(4, 13), (5, 14), (6, 15)]]
```

Which again might be more efficient than the other version, but I think you pay a slight price in code clarity (though others may disagree).

Comment: @KayZhu -- Yeah, I wasn't sure if I wanted to mention it simply because you don't see multiple argument `map` very often.  Since it's not a particularly familiar idiom I hesitate to use it ... But I don't think you'll find a way to do it in less characters ...

Comment: yes I would agree that I'd prefer the existing code without `map`. But it's good to know there's another, shorter way to do it :)

Comment: @KayZhu -- I also always thought it was a little funny that `map(None,a,b)` is basically a `list(izip_longest(a,b,fillvalue=None))`

Comment: I knew there was a neat map-based oneliner in here somewhere, but it didn't occur to me to pass the arguments to `map` separately. My thought was to use `starmap`: `list(itertools.starmap(zip, zip(a, b)))`.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> [zip(i, j) for i, j in zip(a,b)]
[[(1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 12)], [(4, 13), (5, 14), (6, 15)]]
```

Of course, this is really just the same thing that you wrote above.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @mgilson said, you can also consider using [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) if the lists you are zipping are big.

Since `izip` computes elements only when requested and only returns an iterator, the memory usage is much less than `zip` for large lists.

Answer (score 1):

This works well too:

```
print zip(sum(a,[]),sum(b,[]))
```

prints:

```
[(1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 12), (4, 13), (5, 14), (6, 15)]
```

This is probably the best performance wise and is concise as well:

```
from itertools import chain
print zip(chain(*a),chain(*b))
```

same output